# Inserting a new list item into its correct alphabetical position

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm wondering what is the most efficient way of inserting an item (in this case, a string), into its correct alphabetical order, with ONLY JavaScript (not jQuery)? I thought that by sorting the list straight after inserting the item would be sufficient, but doesn't work. I am getting the value to be inserted via a value entered into a textfield.

Before inserting the new item, the list looks like:

- Albatross
- Fantail
- Kea
- Kiwi
- Takahe
- Tui

If I choose to add "Bellbird" to this list, I would expect the list to now look like:

- Albatross
- Bellbird
- Fantail
- Kea
- Kiwi
- Takahe
- Tui

Here is the code I am using to try and achieve the desired outcome:

***HTML:***

```
<ul id="birds">
  <li>Albatross</li>
  <li>Fantail</li>
  <li>Kea</li>
  <li>Kiwi</li>
  <li>Takahe</li>
  <li>Tui</li>
</ul>

<p><label for="addNewBirdField">Add new bird: </label>
   <input type="text" id="addNewBirdField" /></p>

<p><button id ="addItem">Add new bird</button></p>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
function addNewBird()
{
  var birdList = document.getElementById("birds"); //get birds unordered list

  var newBirdItem = document.createElement("li"); // create new li element

  var bird = document.getElementById("addNewBirdField").value // get data from form field

  var birdValue = document.createTextNode(bird); // create new textNode with value from previous step

  newBirdItem.appendChild(birdValue); // append textNode from previous step to li element (newBirdItem)

  birdList.appendChild(newBirdItem); // append li element to bird list

  birdList.sort();
}

var addItem = document.getElementById("addItem");
addItem.onclick = addNewBird;
```

I've looked at [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) at sorting arrays (I am assuming with my knowledge on programming that each list element is in an array). I understand what lexicographically sorting is - I learned this earlier this week.

If anyone can help me out on this one  would be very grateful.

Comment: Well from my point, sort() would work fine but calling sort on birdList (which is not an array, but a ul DOM element) wouldn't make sense. Get all the li elements and sort them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
birdList.sort();
```

This will not work, as the value returned by `document.getElementById()` is *never* an `Array`, it's either a reference to an element or `null` if the element wasn't found. Only `Array`s (by default) have a `sort()` method.

Instead, what you want is...

```
var birds = birdList.getElementsByTagName("li");

birds = Array.prototype.slice.call(birds).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.firstChild.data.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.firstChild.data.toLowerCase());
});

for (var i = 0, length = birds.length; i < length; i++) {
    birdList.appendChild(birds[i]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UCgaB/).

If you didn't need to support older browsers...

```
var birds = birdList.querySelectorAll("li");

birds = Array.prototype.slice.call(birds).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.textContent.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.textContent.toLowerCase());
}).forEach(function(bird) {
    birdList.appendChild(bird);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MabhY/).

Finally, if you *did* have jQuery at your disposal...

```
$(birdList).find("li").sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toLowerCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toLowerCase());
}).each(function() {
    $(birdList).append(this);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhQPc/).

Comment: That worked! :). It took me a little while to read over the statement (Array.prototype.....) to understand what it is doing. It's something I have yet to come across, my understanding is that an anonymous function is being created "on the fly" which compares two values, then is parsed through the sort() function to lexicographically sort the values of each list item by alphabetical order.

I also tried having something like "var birds = birdList.getElementsByTagName("li");" and using the normal birdList.sort - but I now have an idea why it didn't work.

Comment: what is "this" referring to in the last line of your jQuery example? birdList lis?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to re-sort the entire list, and reinsert every item.

You could just find the position in the sorted list to insert the new item.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Test Page</title>


<script>
function addNewBird(){
    var bird= document.getElementById("addNewBirdField").value;
    if(bird){
        bird= bird.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ bird.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        var birdList= document.getElementById("birds"),
        list= birdList.getElementsByTagName('li'),
        i= 0, who= list[0],

        newBirdItem= document.createElement("li");
        newBirdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(bird));

        while(who && who.innerHTML<bird) who= list[++i];
        if(who) birdList.insertBefore(newBirdItem, who);
        else birdList.appendChild(newBirdItem);
    }
    return newBirdItem;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<ul id="birds">
  <li>Albatross</li>
  <li>Fantail</li>
  <li>Kea</li>
  <li>Kiwi</li>
  <li>Takahe</li>
  <li>Tui</li>
</ul>

<p><label for="addNewBirdField">Add new bird: </label>
<input type="text" id="addNewBirdField" /></p>

<p><button id ="addItem" onclick="addNewBird()">Add new bird</button></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```